# Have to pass a single string to multiple regex patterns and on match I want the matched values

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Say I have three Regex's stored in 3 variable's as follow;

```
  string regex1 = @"Regex 1 Pattern";
  string regex2 = @"Regex 2 Pattern";
  string regex3 = @"Regex 3 Pattern";
```

and Now I Passed a single string through a textbox for its test, How could I compare it all to the Regex's declared and on the match how could I retrieve its value on the regex that it is matching?

As per a Single pattern for its comparison the code would be like:

```
 Regex r = new Regex(regex1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But I want my string to through all the patterns declared.

Comment: What is preventing you from creating several instances of `Regex` with all patterns you need, applying all of them one-by-one and obtaining results?

Comment: Do you need to return a special warning per each of the patterns? If not, they can be joined with '|', and test the string only once. Like this: `Regex r = new Regex(regex1 + "|" + regex2 + "|" + regex3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`. Or create a string list/array and then use `String.Join()`.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev basically its a search feature, from which I have to extract keywords on the basis of data type the users enters in a search bar,  so It could further filter the results from the collection on the basis of keywords.

Comment: @MudasirSahto: That doesn't help me understand what the problem is with creating several Regex and running them separately. At the moment your problem seems to be that you want to run three regex and there is nothing obvious stopping you from creating a Regex object three times with three different patterns. Are you limited by things that you haven't got in this question (eg that you are passing the regex to an external unchangeable thing that will only accept one)? With three regex you can extract the keywords in three steps and then combine those keywords after I'd have thought...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list of patterns (you are not limited to just 3), then, you'll be able to check if the input string matches.

```
var patterns = new string[] { @"Regex 1 Pattern", @"Regex 2 Pattern", @"Regex 3 Pattern" };
var rx = new Regex(string.Join("|", patterns), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```